# Covariance of uniform distribution and it's square

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, covariance

I have $X$ ~ $U(-1,1)$ and $Y = X^2$ random variables, I need to calculate their covariance.
My calculations are:
$$
Cov(X,Y) = Cov(X,X^2) = E((X-E(X))(X^2-E(X^2))) = E(X X^2) = E(X^3) = 0
$$
because
$$
E(X) = E(X^2) = 0
$$
I'm not sure about the $X^3$ part, are my calculations correct?

Comment: Note: $\mathsf E[X^2] = \frac 1 3$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\begin{align}
\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y) & =
\mathsf{Cov}(X,X^2)
\\[1ex]
 & = \mathsf E((X-\mathsf E(X))\;(X^2-\mathsf E(X^2)))
\\[1ex]
 & = \mathsf E(X^3-X^2\mathsf E(X)-X\mathsf E(X^2)+\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(X^2))
 & \text{ by expansion}
\\[1ex]
 & = \mathsf E(X^3)-\mathsf E(X^2)\mathsf E(X)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(X^2)+\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(X^2)
 & \text{ by linearity of expectation}
\\[1ex]
 & = \int_{-1}^1 \tfrac 1 2 x^3\operatorname d x -\int_{-1}^1 \tfrac 1 2 x^2\operatorname d x\cdot\int_{-1}^1 \tfrac 1 2 x\operatorname d x
 & \text{ by definition of expectation}
\\[1ex] & = 0
\end{align}$

**Reason** The integrals of the odd functions are both zero over that domain.  $\;\mathsf E(X^3)=\mathsf E(X) = 0$.

*Note that* $\;\mathsf E(X^2) = \int_{-1}^1 \tfrac 12 x^2 \operatorname d x = \tfrac 1 3$

Answer (score 0):

We know it is $E(X^3)$ so:

$$E(X^3)=\int_{-1}^{1}x^3f(x)=0$$

So it is correct

Comment: But why do we know that E(X*X^2) = E(X^3)?

Comment: @AndrásSzilveszter It is completely obvious, since $X.X^2=X^3$